# How to return distinct highlighted words in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I m trying to implement autocomplete in my application. 
say I have the following documents:

```
"red smart phone"
"super smart phone"
"small bluetooth speaker"
```

So when the user types "s" I need to return as suggestions:

```
"smart"
"small"
```

Currently I m using simple highlight in Elasticsearch to get the matched words (smart, small). However the thing is that I get back 2 times the "smart". Is it possible to configure ES return only distinct values for the Highlight?

On top of that is it possible to let ES return also the next (n) word(s) , e.g.:

```
"smart phone"
"small bluetooth (speaker)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The completion suggester seems to be the solution for your need:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

You have to modify your ES mapping to add new properties on your field. 
Be careful of your analyzer too.

HtH,

NicolasY.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, the issue with completion suggester is that i need to explicitly specify the input and output text in the suggest section during indexing. But with almost 1 M documents, this is quite impossible.

Comment: Ok, I get your point, you can use the edgeNgram analyzer instead, but be careful to the configuration, because it could produce heavy memory consumption and ( disk space too ). With this analyzer you have to know how autocompletion will be use, because you have to decide how to split your term at the index time. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Comment: Sure, I already use that together with the Highlight function. Like I said my problem is how to get back only the distinct values of the matched words.

Comment: You're trying to use highlight feature to return specific result, but highlighting isn't explicitly implemented for that. To reduce the number of results, did you try to use the term aggregation instead ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: In other words Nicolas my issue is, given the 3 documents in my question what strategy would you follow to obtain the following response: "smart", "small, when the user types "s"?